# IPv6 scope ID vs IPv4

Tags: sockets, ipv6, ipv4, berkeley-sockets

Recently I was working with the Berkeley socket API for IPv6, and noticed that IPv6 addresses (`sockaddr_in6`) have a field called `sin6_scope_id`, which was not part of IPv4 addresses.

After searching around a bit, I’ve learned that `scope_id` is meant to identify the network interface, because multiple network interfaces can have the same link-local IPv6 address. This made sense, but then what I didn’t understand is how IPv4 handles this issue, if there’s no equivalent of scope ID there?

Is there a mechanism in the kernel that prevents multiple IPv4 interfaces from being assigned the same link-local address?

If that’s the case, then why was it necessary to invent scope ID for IPv6 instead of going with the same solution as IPv4?

Also, is the scope_id only used to distinguish between interfaces with identical link-local addresses, or are there other use cases too?

Comment: It's really that multiple interfaces all have the same IPv6 link-local _network_. The destination address is what determines which interface is used, and if the destination is a link-local address, the host cannot determine which interface to use because they all have the same network. Multiple interfaces with the same network can be a problem for IPv4.

Comment: While IPv4 _has_ link local addresses, they're rarely used, and their presence usually indicates a serious problem. With IPv6, _every_ interface _always_ has a link local address, and they are _often_ used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, no, there is no well-defined mechanism for handling link-local IPv4 addresses on hosts with multiple interfaces. There is nothing stopping the same link-local address being selected for two different interfaces (however if the two interfaces are on the same network link, then ARP-based conflict detection will cause at least one of them to be reassigned).

[RFC 3927 section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927#section-3.2) covers the issues of "address ambiguity":

> Given that the IP stack must have the outbound interface associated
> with a packet that needs to be sent to a Link-Local destination
> address, interface selection must occur.  The outbound interface
> cannot be derived from the packet's header parameters such as source
> or destination address (e.g., by using the forwarding table lookup).
> Therefore, outbound interface association must be done explicitly
> through other means.  The specification does not stipulate those
> means.

And also in [section 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927#section-6.3):

> Application software run on a multi-homed host that supports IPv4
> Link-Local address configuration on more than one interface may fail.
>
> This is because application software assumes that an IPv4 address is
> unambiguous, that it can refer to only one host.  IPv4 Link-Local
> addresses are unique only on a single link.  A host attached to
> multiple links can easily encounter a situation where the same
> address is present on more than one interface, or first on one
> interface, later on another; in any case associated with more than
> one host.  Most existing software is not prepared for this ambiguity.
> In the future, application programming interfaces could be developed
> to prevent this problem.

This problem was solved in IPv6 by the introduction of a **scope ID**.

At present [scope id is only used for link-local addressing](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/46657).